# After re-compiling the kernel, my grub stop after the bios

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, crux

After recompiling my kernel, I copied the corresponding files to `/boot`, and my `/boot` directory looks like:

[image]

Then, I inserted a new item in `grub`, and `/boot/grub/menu.lst` now looks like:

[image]

After searching a lot, I found that someone mentions that maybe ACPI settings matter. So, I set ACPI to off. But it still does not work.
When I reboot my OS, it still stops, like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have another `grub` item, `grub-ide`. And if I choose it, I can successfully log into it.

How can I get my system to boot with my new kernel?

Comment: Recompile kernel again without making any changes that you did to it. Good start as always would be "make mrproper" to clean up.
Use .config to your advantage if you are compiling kernel from kernel.org sources.

Comment: i have already tried twice，but it still does not work.And by the way,i have rewrite something of the kernel at the fisrttime i boot the kernel.But i donn't think it's the problem.

Comment: What is `vmlinuz-noexec` and how does it relate to `vmlinuz`? The `noexec` bit makes me suspicious; Also, does booting the first entry without `acpi=off` help?

(Also, note that it's not grub that's stopping, I think the "Uncompressing Linux..." part is already under Linux control (although I can't find it in the arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c, it lives there for other architectures).)

Comment: for the sake that i have changed something in the kernel,i recompile the bzImage and rename it as vmlinuz-noexec.So,u can see in my /boot directory there are vmlinuz which is the orignal version and the vmlinuz-noexec i have aready changed.And coming to acpi,at the first-time i set the grub item of the vmlinuz-noexec without acpi,but it does worked yet.And after long time searching,someone mention maybe the acpi setting matter,so i set the acpi to off,but it has no change yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was nothing with the setting, but was about my own design of the kernel. After revising some of the bug, the kernel can be booted successfully:
[image: screenshot after successful boot]